# C++ winform combobox selected Value

Tags: c++

I have a program that works perfectly, but I Made a interface for it and shoved all the code into it. But for user input , I am having difficulties getting the combo box selected value into std::string that the program uses.

Comment: Not really any code to post, Just how can I get current selected value of combo box into string     std::string atOne = (this->comboBox1)->Text; but says system string conversion error

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, I figured it out. `String^ test = (this->comboBox1)->Text;`. The whole time I was saying `std::String^` but needed to take out std.

Comment: You see? This is why it's helpful to see code so we can spot out mistakes like these. :)